Google Cloud Composer 3 not using Default Service Account in DAG Task
Trying to invoke Cloud Function from Cloud Composer for a Customer POC in a Free Trial Account
I am using

Cloud Function Version 2 powered by Cloud Run - Default Python Hello World Cloud Function
Cloud Composer Version 3 for invoking Cloud Function

Below is the Airflow DAG Code
import datetime
import os


from airflow import models
from airflow.utils import trigger_rule

import json
from datetime import timedelta

import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.hooks.http_hook import HttpHook

from google.oauth2 import id_token, service_account
import google.auth.transport
import jwt

import requests

default_dag_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'retries': 0
}

with models.DAG(
        'smks_dag',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1440),
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    def invoke_cloud_function():
        endpoint=f'https://us-central1-<project_number>.cloudfunctions.net/<cloud_function_name>'
        auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
        id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, endpoint)    
        print("Decoded:", jwt.decode(id_token, options={"verify_signature": False}))
        headers = {
                    "Authorization": f"Bearer {id_token}",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
        request_body={ "name": "KIDDDOOO"}
        response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, json=request_body)
        print(response.text)                        
    
    call_gcf1 = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='invoke_cloud_function',
        python_callable=invoke_cloud_function
    )    

    call_gcf1


The code is pretty simple
One Task which

Gets the IDToken for the current Service Account used by Task
Prints the Decoded JWT Token
Call Cloud Function with request body
Print the response back

DAG Run Log
[2024-08-03, 05:11:35 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - Decoded: {'aud': 'https://us-central1-loyal-polymer-431316-n6.cloudfunctions.net/smks_test', 'azp': '', 'email': 'peervm-vm@fcca17c49141c7cacp-tp.iam.gserviceaccount.com', 'email_verified': True, 'exp': 1722665495, 'google': {'compute_engine': {'instance_creation_timestamp': 1722660473, 'instance_id': '2373055827394168984', 'instance_name': 'peer-vm-instance-10-z2mc6', 'project_id': '-tp', 'project_number': , 'zone': 'us-central1-f'}}, 'iat': , 'iss': 'https://accounts.google.com', 'sub': ''}
[2024-08-03, 05:11:35 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - \n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>\n<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/smks_test</code> from this server.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>
[2024-08-03, 05:11:35 UTC] {python.py:237} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None

The problem is the Service Account printed in Decode Statement is peervm-vm@fcca17c49141c7cacp-tp.iam.gserviceaccount.com instead of default Compute Service Account 330684351669-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com configured in composer

I am not sure why this is happening, I have checked the Google Cloud Composer Access Control Documentation
I have assigned the Cloud Composer v2 API Service Agent Extension role to the
Cloud Composer Service Agent account service-330684351669@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com (different from the Service Account)

Please let me know how we can get the Default Service Account for DAG Task instead of some strange one
peervm-vm@fcca17c49141c7cacp-tp.iam.gserviceaccount.com created by Composer 3 Kubernetes Setup.Because of this the IDToken does not have permissions to invoke the Cloud Functions Version 2 which needs authentication
I am also not sure if this is related to the error
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/728
Just to let you know I even tried the option given here as an example of Composer 2, but it also is never authenticated
https://github.com/salrashid123/composer_gcf
